# How to log account creation date on FreeRADIUS?

Tags: freeradius

How to log account creation date on FreeRADIUS?
This is not a connection-checking information, creation date needs only for informational logging.

Comment: Where would that information come from?

Comment: from php script, for example.

Comment: and where would you be logging the information to?

Comment: In the radius database, but i don't know which table and column i should use.

Comment: You'd use the postauth table, and add your own column to the schema.

Which version of FreeRADIUS is this?